# Function to match a field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to return a value (ID), matching another field (Type) in the array.

Object array:

```
a: Array[3]
0: Object
1: Object
Desc: "Desc"
ID: "V000002"
Type: "SK"
__proto__: Object
2: Object
length: 3
```

find method:

```
ns.find = function (a) {
        $.each( a, function (k, v) {
                if (v.Type == 'SK') {
                    return v.ID
                }
            }
        );
        return "";
    }  ;
```

It doesn't work even though there is a match. what's wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ns.find = function (a) {
    var val = '';
    $.each( a, function (k, v) {
        if (v.Type == 'SK') {
            val = v.ID;
            return false;
        }
    );
    return val;
};
```

The `return` statement inside of `jQuery.each` won't break out of your `ns.find` method, just the current loop iteration. To break out of `jQuery.each`, you need to return `false`;